# Standarzing double quotes, single quotes and apostrophes in python

Tags: python-3.x, regex, nlp, quotes, double-quotes

Since I am working with many different fonts and have a special treatment for each of these symbols, I would like to standardize all quote and apostrophe entries in my text fonts.

I'm looking for something similar to this entry for skip lines

```
content=re.sub(r'\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]', '\n', content)
```

or for hyphens

```
content = regex.sub(r'\p{Pd}+', '-', content)
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Did you get the help you needed ? Cause I can't recall how you can get an exact solution to you're problem, yet you marked @WiktorStribiżew as a direct answer. But there is _NO Direct_ solution as I stated in my answer, yet you didn't mark it.. Just curious as to what your thinking is herre ?

Comment: And I've got the tools to give you specific solution compromises, but you may have burned that bridge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the [Uniview](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/) tool you could search for all Unicode symbols that contain reference to "single quotation mark", "double quotation mark", "apostrophe",e.g.

[image]

Here are somewhat pruned outputs:

**Single quotation marks, `[\u02BB\u02BC\u066C\u2018-\u201A\u275B\u275C]`** (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hLTYs6/1)):

- `ʻ` - ‎02BB MODIFIER LETTER TURNED COMMA
- `ʼ` - ‎02BC MODIFIER LETTER APOSTROPHE
- `٬` - ‎066C ARABIC THOUSANDS SEPARATOR
- `‘` - ‎2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
- `’` - ‎2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
- `‚` - ‎201A SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
- `❛` - ‎275B HEAVY SINGLE TURNED COMMA QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT
- `❜` - ‎275C HEAVY SINGLE COMMA QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT

**Double quotation marks, `[\u201C-\u201E\u2033\u275D\u275E\u301D\u301E]`** (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hLTYs6/2)):

- `“` - ‎201C LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
- `”` - ‎201D RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
- `„` - ‎201E DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
- `″` - ‎2033 DOUBLE PRIME
- `❝` - ‎275D HEAVY DOUBLE TURNED COMMA QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT
- `❞`  -‎275E HEAVY DOUBLE COMMA QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT
- `〝`  -‎301D REVERSED DOUBLE PRIME QUOTATION MARK
- `〞` - ‎301E DOUBLE PRIME QUOTATION MARK

**Apostrophes, `[\u0027\u02B9\u02BB\u02BC\u02BE\u02C8\u02EE\u0301\u0313\u0315\u055A\u05F3\u07F4\u07F5\u1FBF\u2018\u2019\u2032\uA78C\uFF07]`** (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hLTYs6/3)):

- `'` - ‎0027 APOSTROPHE
- `ʹ` ‎- 02B9 MODIFIER LETTER PRIME
- `ʻ` ‎- 02BB MODIFIER LETTER TURNED COMMA
- `ʼ` ‎- 02BC MODIFIER LETTER APOSTROPHE
- `ʾ` - ‎02BE MODIFIER LETTER RIGHT HALF RING
- `ˈ` - ‎02C8 MODIFIER LETTER VERTICAL LINE
- `ˮ` - ‎02EE MODIFIER LETTER DOUBLE APOSTROPHE
- `́ ‎` - 0301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
- `̓` - ‎0313 COMBINING COMMA ABOVE
- `̕` - ‎0315 COMBINING COMMA ABOVE RIGHT
- `՚` - ‎055A ARMENIAN APOSTROPHE
- `׳` - ‎05F3 HEBREW PUNCTUATION GERESH
- `ߴ` - ‎07F4 NKO HIGH TONE APOSTROPHE
- `ߵ` - ‎07F5 NKO LOW TONE APOSTROPHE
- `᾿` - ‎1FBF GREEK PSILI
- `‘` - ‎2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
- `’` - ‎2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
- `′` - ‎2032 PRIME
- `ꞌ` - ‎A78C LATIN SMALL LETTER SALTILLO
- `＇` - ‎FF07 FULLWIDTH APOSTROPHE

Answer (score 1):

Note that these categories are subjective.
For example, there is no single Unicode property for *Single Quote*
or *Double Quote* that will give you the span you're looking for.
But, you could play around with subsets, for example

`\p{Block=General_Punctuation}(?<=\p{Quotation_Mark})`
will give the subset of these `‘’‚‛“”„‟‹›`

Whereas using just `\p{Quotation_Mark}`
will give this subset `"'«»‘’‚‛“”„‟‹›⹂「」『』〝〞〟﹁﹂﹃﹄＂＇｢｣`
where some might be questionable quotation marks.

Here's another one   `\p{Line_Break=Quotation}`
which gives these  `"'«»‘’‛“”‟‹›❛❜❝❞❟❠⸀⸁⸂⸃⸄⸅⸆⸇⸈⸉⸊⸋⸌⸍⸜⸝⸠⸡`

So, be warned, there is no definitive *SET* according to Unicode
specs.

---

Probably for the hyphen `\p{Pd}` , the equivalent regex would be

```
find    (?:[\u002D\u058A\u05BE\u1400\u1806\u2010-\u2015\u2E17\u2E1A\u2E3A\u2E3B\u2E40\u301C\u3030\u30A0\uFE31\uFE32\uFE58\uFE63\uFF0D]|\uD803\uDEAD)
replace -
```

And for the single quote

```
find:   [\u0060\u00B4\u2018\u2019]
replace '
```

And for double quote

```
find    [\u201C\u201D]
replace "
```

---

Also note that every character has many Unicode properties
that will match it, so traversing a sample string you can see
overlapping property relationship, like here ->

[image]

Comment: Yes, somebody downloaded this. I do not know the reason.